# A 'hello world' example for a major mode in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, major-mode

Can anyone provide me with a hello world example for a major mode in emacs? 
I guess it's a beginner question, still I really like to write a major mode, both to learn emacs and elisp, as to be able to use customization to the fullest.

What I have done so far (and is working) :

- wrote a file sample-mode.el and put it in a lisp dir
- called in .emacs `(require 'sample-mode)`
- wrote some defuns in it, and provided it at the end `(provide 'sample-mode)`

But still it doesn't seem to be *activated*, I cannot call it with M-sample-mode.

So how to do that? And can anyone provide me with a very very simple Hello World like working sample?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, after some more googling I am at least one step furhter :

```
(define-derived-mode sample-mode ...)
```

since the providing isn't defining the mode as I thought first..
This I found on :

[http://xahlee.org/emacs/elisp_syntax_coloring.html](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/elisp_syntax_coloring.html)

A very very nice site for emacs-lovers.

With the help of that : I have made a HelloWorld example myself now : It's a (as small as possible) Csharp mode.  I have used [Euler1](https://projecteuler.net/) as example rather than HelloWorld.  The files you need to know about are :

- the file the mode will be applied on  `Euler1.cs`
- the .emacs
- and of course the mode itself

Since a pic is worth, at least a bunch of words : all files on 1 screen :

[image]

But since this nice pic seems to disappear half the time (anyone a clue? Open in new tab always brings it on, and the url is ok) some words too :-) :

1. The mode : cs-mode.el

   > ```
   > (setq myKeywords 
   >  '(("WriteLine" . font-lock-function-name-face)
   >    ("public\\|static\\|void\\|int\\|for\\|if\\|class"
   > . font-lock-constant-face)))
   >
   > (define-derived-mode cs-mode fundamental-mode
   >   (setq font-lock-defaults '(myKeywords)))
   >
   > (provide 'cs-mode)
   > ```
2. The .emacs, that makes the .cs files open in the right mode :

> ```
> ;; cs
> (require 'cs-mode)
> (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.cs\\'" . cs-mode))
> ```

And thats all : the `cs-code` itself is useless her, cause it won't show the effect of coloring the key-words.  To see that see the pic, or open the pic in another tab/window.

Cheers, ph

Comment: @jrockway : not agreeing here, I learned a lot from him, including writing major modes
Although he might himself not have any spare time left th include his own ideas, you have a point there

Comment: @jrockaway: that is the second time I see you criticising Xah... why do you hate him so much?

Comment: ps, there is a more full-featured C# mode: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CSharpMode

Comment: @Vivi Xah is well-known in Emacs circles, and not in a good way.

Comment: @R.P.Dillon , imho this asks for some elaboration, otherwise your comment seems too nonbinding.  I don't know Xah, but learned a lot from his site.

Answer (score 6):

there are several examples around the Web [like this](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Major-Modes).
I can also recommend you several Emacs book:

- Learning GNU Emacs (the best imho)
- Writing GNU Emacs Extensions
- the official GNU Emacs lisp reference/manual

Comment: +1 and thanks for the link, but in the whole emacs scene, sometimes a lack of simple examples bothers me a bit.  One notable exception the link provided earlier : xahlee.org

Answer (score 6):

Well, let's start with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756666/match-regular-expression-as-keyword-in-define-generic-mode/756927#756927), which uses [`define-generic-mode`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Generic-Modes.html).

Flesh it out with some comment characters like: `/* */`, some keywords: `hello` `hi` etc., re-use the face from the original answer, a file extension `.hello`, and a function call to do further customization.

There's the additional line to get autoloading working, but you have to [generate the loaddefs.el](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Autoload.html) file.  That's more advanced than hello world.

And, you end up with this:

```
(make-face 'my-date-face)
(set-face-attribute 'my-date-face nil :underline t)
(set-face-attribute 'my-date-face nil :family "times")
(set-face-attribute 'my-date-face nil :slant 'normal)
(set-face-attribute 'my-date-face nil :height '340)

;;;###autoload
(define-generic-mode hello-world
  '(("/*" . "*/"))                           ; comment characters
  '("hello" "hi" "howdy" "greetings" "hola") ; keywords
  '(("\\([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+\\)"
     (1 'my-date-face)))                ; font lock
  '("\\.hello$")                        ; auto-mode-alist  
  '(hello-world-special-setup)          ; function-list
  "An example major mode.
We have comments, keywords, a special face for dates, and recognize .hello files.")

(defun hello-world-special-setup ()
  "Some custom setup stuff done here by mode writer."
  (message "You've just enabled the most amazing mode ever."))
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be called ` hello-world-mode` ?

Answer (score 2):

The Elisp manual introduces major modes pretty well, and it includes a node that presents "hello-world" [**examples**](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Example-Major-Modes.html). At least that is the intention, I think.

Those examples might not cover everything you are looking for. In that case, consider requesting whatever you think is missing that would help users more. To do that, use **`M-x report-emacs-bug`** (that is for enhancement requests also).